# Hiding rows based on the values in two columns of the same row

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a macro button that does one thing in two steps. This is for a progress tracker, if a task is marked completed in column G, then I need the row hidden.

That command I have completed below, however step two of this is if the value in column c "Name" is hidden (based on the first command) then I need all other values in column C, equal to the values of the hidden rows, hidden as well. The goal of this is to return all items actively in progress by eliminating any names in row C that have a "completed" task under them.

'Step 1: (Works to hide completed rows)

```
Sub HideCompletes()
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("G5:G200") 'would love to have this work for all cells after G5, but not sure how to acomplish that either
If cell.Value = "Completed" Or cell.Value = "" Then
cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next cell
```

'Step 2: (non functional idea)

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("G5:G200")
If cell.RowHeight = 0 And cell.Value In ActiveSheet.Range("C5:C200")
cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: A cell with `RowHeight` = 0 is already hidden, I would say... What `cell.Value In ActiveSheet.Range("C5:C200")` wants to mean? Can you explain that in words?

Comment: I'm just trying to hide more cells based off of the ones that are already hidden from the first part of the code if that makes sense. The line there is a partial start at refering to the values in column C of the hidden cells. Written its, if a cells value in column c with row height not equal to 0 is equal to the value in column c of a hidden row, then hide row.

Comment: If a cell is hidden, entire row is hidden, too... From its perspective. Can you also explaining what `cell.Value In ActiveSheet.Range("C5:C200")` means?

Comment: Sorry if thats confusing on readback, l meant rows based on the cells. I guess said more simply its: If a non hidden rows value (in column C) is equal to the value of any hidden row (column c of the hidden row) then hide that row.

Comment: The lines from step 2 are a ways from what they need to be from my written form above the cell.Value In ActiveSheet.Range("C5:C200") is a placeholder attempt to call all the individual cell values in that column from C5 on to compare to the values of hidden rows

Comment: In order to specify that a cell is hidden, it is good to use `Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True`. If you need to compare a specific cell with some other in column C:C, you must set the comparison value and then compare it with each of that specific range cell.

Comment: Just noticed that line one of step 2 in my code should be "C5:C200" not "G5:G200" I'm comparing column C values to Column C values under the condition if Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  If cell Gx is "Completed" or "" then you want to hide that row.  Then after that you want to loop through all the rows and hide any that have the same value in column C as the row that you hid originally.  Right?

Comment: Exactly yes, thanks Jerry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub HideCompletes()
    ' first find the last row in the spreadsheet that has data
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

    ' now loop through the cells in G and hide them if they are completed
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("G5:G" & lastrow)
        If cell.Value = "Completed" Or cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True

            ' get the value from column C for that row
            Dim hiddenvalue As Variant
            hiddenvalue = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & cell.Row)

            ' now loop through the cells in C and hide them if they match our hidden value
            ' the value 0 will match an empty cell so we need to check both conditions
            For Each othercell In ActiveSheet.Range("C5:C" & lastrow)
                If othercell.Value <> "" And othercell.Value = hiddenvalue Then
                    othercell.EntireRow.Hidden = True

                End If
            Next othercell

        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I think it does what you want.  If cell in G is "Completed" or "" then it hides that row. Then after that it loops through all the rows and hides any that have the same value in column C as the row that was hidden originally.

Comment: Took me some time to unpack all of how this works, but its perfect and works great thank you!